# Is it possible to use WKS type Systems and Conversation Entities toghether

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, watson-conversation, watson-nlu

I am trying to add watson knowledge studio model via discovery to a chatbot built on conversation. The question I have is that when I start using WKS model with its own Type systems, then how will the entities already defined in conversations be used.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Knowledge Studio and Conversation do not have method of direct integration. If you already have Entities definition in you Conversation workspace, you have to convert them into Knowledge Studio manually.
I have to note that usage of entities or entity type in Knowledge Studio and Conversation are not same and you need some conversion on your Entities gotten from Conversation before ingesting them to Knowledge Studio.